# Use sleep with minutes and seconds

Tags: command-line, coreutils

I know how to use sleep 5m for 5 minutes.

How would I use it for say 7 mins 30 seconds?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sleep.1.html):

> Given two or more arguments, pause for the amount of time specified 
>   by **the sum of their values**.

So:

```
sleep 7m 30s
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that this is  `bash` built-in and GNU `sleep`  behavior. POSIXly, `sleep` is only required to understand integers as seconds

Answer (score 17):

Another way to do this is:

```
sleep 7.5m
```

```
man sleep
```

> Unlike most implementations that require  NUMBER
>          be  an  integer,  here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.

Answer (score 10):

There are two excellent answers already but I'd like to expand a bit. Copy and paste command below into your terminal:

```
$ sleep 3d 5h 7m 30.05s &
[1] 7321
```

This will start a second process that will sleep for 3 days, 5 hours, 7 minutes and 30.05 seconds. The process ID (PID) is `7321` in my case.

To confirm the PID use

```
$ ps aux | grep sleep
rick      7321  0.0  0.0  14356   660 pts/2    S    22:40   0:00 sleep 3d 5h 7m 30.05s
root     12415  0.0  0.0  14356   700 ?        S    22:41   0:00 sleep 60
rick     12500  0.0  0.0  21292   968 pts/2    R+   22:41   0:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

The first entry is the one we are interested in. The second entry is for a permanent program I have running in startup. The third entry is for the grep command itself.

Now to see how much time is remaining (in seconds) for the `sleep` command generated by PID `7321` we can use this: [How to determine the amount of time left in a “sleep”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314512/how-to-determine-the-amount-of-time-left-in-a-sleep) command:

```
$ remaining_sleep_time 7321
277304.05
$ remaining_sleep_time 7321
277296.05
$ remaining_sleep_time 7321
277262.05
```

The code for the command you can include in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
remaining_sleep_time() { # arg: pid
  ps -o etime= -o args= -p "$1" | perl -MPOSIX -lane '
    %map = qw(d 86400 h 3600 m 60 s 1);
    $F[0] =~ /(\d+-)?(\d+:)?(\d+):(\d+)/;
    $t = -($4+60*($3+60*($2+24*$1)));
    for (@F[2..$#F]) {
      s/\?//g;
      ($n, $p) = strtod($_);
      $n *= $map{substr($_, -$p)} if $p;
      $t += $n
    }
    print $t'
}
```

Comment: My remaining time is not working. andy@7_~$ remaining_sleep_time 7321
remaining_sleep_time: command not found

Comment: @fixit7 `remaining_sleep_time` needs to be copied into your `~/.bashrc` file as per the link. You could also put the code into a bash script file.

Answer (score 6):

Command sleep is always counting in seconds. You could use ((7x60)+30) seconds and then type simply:

> sleep 450

Comment: As noted [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064484/use-sleep-with-minutes-and-seconds#comment1744266_1064486) , sleep indeed always understands seconds, but in case of GNU sleep and Bash shell ( not sure about ksh and zsh ) - those also allow letter arguments as noted in other answers. Your answer could be improved with using shell arithmetic expansion, so something like `sleep $((60*7))` could be used for minutes